# Spring Aspect for field

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

I have a bean to report to InfluxDB. The Database have in the table `INFLUX_DB_SERVER` registred InfluxDBs. If you look at the code you will see that the Method `reportMemory` do a lot of work, it constructs a Measurement and do call `reportAll`, all this work is useless when there is no InfluxDB.

So the idea is to skip that work if there is no InfluxDB. Since the public-void-methods do not return a value it has no impact to the surrounding application.

What I could do is I could write a method `isWorkPossible` and call the method every call. That might follow KISS but that violates DRY. So I like to archivee that using AOP.

But I like to skip the execution of all public void methods if no InfluxDBs are registred.

```
/**
 * The reporter to notify {@link InfluxDB influxDBs} for changes.
 */
@Named
public class InfluxDBReporter {
    /**
     * Logger for reporting. For security reasons neither the username nor the
     * password should be logged above {@link Level#FINER}.
     */
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(InfluxDBReporter.class.getCanonicalName());

    /**
     * The entitymanager to use, never <code>null</code>.
     */
    @PersistenceContext
    private final EntityManager entityManager = null;

    /**
     * The registred {@link InfluxDBServer} in key and the URL in value.
     */
    @SkipPublicVoidMethodsIfEmpty
    private final Map<InfluxDB, URL> dbs = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    /**
     * Initializes the connections.
     */
    @PostConstruct
    private void connect() {
        for (InfluxDBServer db : FROM(囗InfluxDBServer.class).all(entityManager)) {
            try {
                URL dbUrl = new URL(db.getUrl());
                InfluxDB idb = InfluxDBFactory.connect(db.getUrl(), db.getUsername(), db.getPassword());
                idb.setDatabase(db.getDatabaseName());
                dbs.put(idb, dbUrl);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, db.getUrl(), e);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Closes all connections to all {@link InfluxDB}.
     */
    @PreDestroy
    private void disconnect() {
        for (InfluxDB influxDB : dbs.keySet()) {
            try {
                influxDB.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Fault barrier
                LOG.log(Level.WARNING, "InfluxDBServer URL: " + dbs.get(idb), e);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Report memory statistics.
     * 
     * @param availableProcessors Amount of available processors, never negative.
     * @param totalMemory         The total memory, never negative.
     * @param maxMemory           The max memory, never negative.
     * @param freeMemory          The free memory, never negative.
     */
    public void reportMemory(int availableProcessors, long totalMemory, long maxMemory, long freeMemory) {
        reportAll(Point.measurement("jvm").addField("totalMemory", totalMemory).addField("maxMemory", maxMemory)
                .addField("freeMemory", freeMemory));
    }

    /**
     * Report a point to all connected {@link InfluxDBServer}.
     * 
     * @param builder The point to report.
     */
    private void reportAll(Builder builder) {
        Point infoPoint = builder.time(System.currentTimeMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).build();
        for (InfluxDB idb : dbs.keySet()) {
            new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    idb.write(infoPoint);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Fault barrier
                    LOG.log(Level.WARNING, "InfluxDBServer URL: " + dbs.get(idb), e);
                    throw e;
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my aspect:

```
@Aspect
public class MethodAnnotations {
    @Pointcut("@annotation(xxx.MethodAnnotations.SkipPublicVoidMethodsIfEmpty)")
    private void anyOldTransfer(JoinPoint jp) {
        System.out.println(jp); <----- never executed.
    }

    public @interface SkipPublicVoidMethodsIfEmpty {
    }
}
```

I expect the `System.out.println` to run when the bean is instanticated but it does not.

Any idea why?

Comment: From the documentation: *@annotation: Limits matching to join points where the subject of the join point (the method being executed in Spring AOP) has the given annotation.* I don't see SkipMethodsOnEmpty used anywhere. And I don't see SkipPublicVoidMethodsIfEmpty used on any method. Why do you have that expectation? Why should Spring care about a different annotation, placed on some unrelated field? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Ah, I renamed `SkipMethodsOnEmpty` to `SkipPublicVoidMethodsIfEmpty` but forgot to update the pointcut-expression. Me stupid!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *JB Nizet* already said, `@annotation(my.package.MyAnnotation)` is designed to capture annotations on methods, not on fields, which explains why your expectation for anything to happen there is wrong.

If you want to find out via AOP if a class has a member with a specific annotation, you need to use a special pointcut like `hasfield(@MyAnnotation * *)`. But that pointcut is unavailable in Spring AOP, you need to [switch to AspectJ](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-using-aspectj). The same is true if you want to intercept read/write access to such fields via `get(@MyAnnotation MyType *)` or `set(@MyAnnotation MyType *)`.

For more details see [my other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56788724/1082681).

AspectJ also provides special pointcuts

- to intercept static initialisation of a class after class-loading -> `staticinitialization()`
- to intercept constructor execution -> `MyType.new()`

You can use those in order to execute your aspect advice whenever it is the right time to do so. In your example you could also more easily hook into `@PostConstruct` methods if it is clear that all target classes have one of those.

My answer is quite generic because you do not explain in detail what exactly you want to do. So feel free to ask follow-up questions.

---

**Update**: I checked your latest question update. I don't get it, this is a very contrived solution for a very simple problem also not a good case to be solved by AOP. As much as I love AOP, I am failing to see how this situation is a cross-cutting concern:

- It seems to affect only a single class, `InfluxDBReporter`.
- You are using an annotation which exists for the sole purpose of telling an aspect what to do.
- To make things worse, you put the annotation onto a private field, but expect an external class (an aspect in this case) to react on it. While this is technically possible with AspectJ, it is bad design because you are bleeding private information to the outside.
- By skipping the public method from your sample class you do not save any expensive DB-related operations because iterating over an empty `KeySet` means that just nothing will happen, so there also will not be any DB-related errors. The only thing really happening here are the builder calls. They should be cheap.

Even assuming you have many more public methods which should be skipped, I would actually design the AOP solution like this if you do want to stick with the approach:

- Add a method `public boolean isConnectedToDB() { return !dbs.isEmpty(); }` to your application class.
- In your aspect, use an `@Around` advice and call the boolean method from there, only calling `joinPoint.proceed()` if there are any connections. Otherwise don't proceed but do nothing instead (for `void` methods) or return a dummy result like `null` (for non-`void` methods).

The exact solution depends on whether you have only this one class or multiple ones with similar requirements, if you only have `public void` methods or also non-void ones.

Besides, you are mentioning `INFLUX_DB_SERVER` but I have no idea what this is because I cannot see it anywhere in your code.

Last, but not least: I just noticed that you expect something to happen in a method annotated by `@Pointcut`. Sorry, even if the pointcut was not wrong sothing would happen there because a pointcut definition is just to be used in an actual advice method such as `@Before`, `@After`, `@Around`. The actions you want to be performed go into the advice, not into the pointcut. I suggest you learn AOP basics first before you try to design AOP-based solutions.

Comment: Updated question. But the hard fact is that `@annotation(my.package.MyAnnotation)` does not affect fields. This is a bad-supprise to me!

Comment: Well, it is documented, so if you have ever read the Spring AOP manual it should not be a surprise.

Comment: I expect hat exception at JavaDoc but couldnt find it at the related position. Ask at SO is more easy. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html is a Bleiwüste and you are AspectJ Coach, why shouldnt I learn from you. :-)

Comment: You mean user manual, not Javadoc. This is what you are linking to. Ignoring the fact that you linked to a very old version (Spring 2.5), still if you search for the very first occurrence of "@annotation", you find [this paragraph](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html#aop-pointcuts-designators), clearly and concisely (no Bleiwüste at all) stating: "limits matching to join points where the subject of the join point (**method being executed** in Spring AOP) has the given annotation". Please also note my answer update after your question update.

Comment: `囗InfluxDBServer` is the entity for the table `INFLUX_DB_SERVER` from the jdbc-artifactory-bridge. To your suggestion, to repeat `@Around` on every public void method violates DRY.

Comment: `annotation onto a private field, but expect an external class (...) to react on it (...) is technically possible with AspectJ`. But I do this successfully with the `EntityManager`, do you mean this is not AspectJ?

Comment: `You mean user manual, not Javadoc. ` No I mean JavaDoc, I first read Javadoc what gives no more information effort in this question. Than I start to read the old manual having an maximum line width of about 600 characters (where only 40-55 match usability-rules) so the manual have bad usability, resizing the manual to 55 characters gives me a print version of 32 pages for one single information. You can not deny the fact that ask in SO is easier.

Comment: You should read my answers more carefully. (1) One `@Around` advice would take care of **all** public methods. (2) What are you "doing successfully" with the entity manager? You said your approach does not work (and I explained in detail why), which is why you asked your question here on SO in the first place. (3) You say Javadoc but link to the manual. Javadoc does not serve the purpose of a tutorial or user manual. (4) Why do you read an outdated manual and not the current version I linked to in my first answer? (5) For me the old doc looks just fine in the browser, both desktop and mobile.

Comment: 1. Ah ok. 2. See my code. You will notice I have a private final field for the `EntityManager` having an annotation `@PersistenceContext`. The instance is autowired by some class outside of the `InfluxDBReporter`. You say it is not possible using AspectJ. 3. I say JavaDoc and I say Manual, the both sentences have nothing to do with each other, thats why I use a `.` to seperate the sentences.  4. Because I use spring 2.5 mate. 5. I use 8k desktop and I do not read 32 pages of documentation in my mobilphone.

Comment: How is `@PersistenceContext` related to Spring AOP? I see no obvious connection. Isn't that Java EE?